# Merging CSV data and counting cell values in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The following link has a very similar problem solved using python dictionaries [Python: merging dictionaries with lists in lists as values and counting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041971/python-merging-dictionaries-with-lists-in-lists-as-values-and-counting-them)

I would like to know if the following problem can be solved using python pandas library. I tried using merge and join but I am not sure how to go about getting the desired result.

The problem is as follows:

From 2 csv files, I read in a dictionary

```
dict1 = {'M1': {'H': '1', 'J' : '2'}, 'M2': {'H': '1', 'J' : '2'}, 'M3': {'H': '1', 'J' : '2'}}
dict2 = {'M1': {'H': '4', 'J' : '6'}, 'M2': {'H': '2', 'J' : '5'}, 'M4': {'H': '9', 'J' : '8'}}
```

Required Output Table:

List of all Keys in both the dictionaries with their sum of sub-dictionary [{H,J}] values for the matching keys between two dictionaries

Example: M1 is present both in dict1 and dict2, so final output for M1 should be

final_M1['H'] = 1 (from dict1['M1']) + 4 (from dict2['M1']) = 5

Similarly for M3, M3 is present only in dict1, so nothing has to be done and that values have to be retained.

Sample Output:

```
---------------------
M    |  H  |   J
---------------------
M1   |  5  |   8
---------------------
M2   |  3  |   7
---------------------
M3   |  1  |   2
---------------------
M4   |  9  |   8
```

To get the unique set of two dictionaries,

```
keys = set(dict1.keys()).union(dict2.keys())
```

Similar to the logic used in the link above, The solution using python dictionary looks like this:

```
for k in keys:
print "Key:", k
d1val = dict1.get(k, {})
d2val = dict2.get(k, {})
if (len(d1val) == 0):
    print "d2val H:", d2val['H']

if (len(d2val) == 0):
    print "d1val H:", d1val['H']

if (len(d1val) != 0 and len(d2val) != 0):
    print "Test"
    print "d1val H:", d1val['H']
    print "d2val H:", d2val['H']
    print "d1val H + d2val H = ", int(d1val['H']) + int(d2val['H'])
print "***********"
```

How to implement the same logic in python pandas? I also would like to if using pandas library for such operation will be efficient considering if the input data set is of the range of 10,000 rows per file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `DataFrame.add` method if the values in the nested dicts were numbers rather than strings. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'M1': {'H': 1, 'J' : 2}, 'M2': {'H': 1, 'J' : 2},
         'M3': {'H': 1, 'J' : 2}}
dict2 = {'M1': {'H': 4, 'J' : 6}, 'M2': {'H': 2, 'J' : 5},
         'M4': {'H': 9, 'J' : 8}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2).T

print(df1)

#     H  J
# M1  1  2
# M2  1  2
# M3  1  2

print(df2)
#     H  J
# M1  4  6
# M2  2  5
# M4  9  8

print(df1.add(df2, fill_value = 0))

#     H  J
# M1  5  8
# M2  3  7
# M3  1  2
# M4  9  8
```

If you show the data in the csv files, perhaps we can suggest how to read it in so that the values are numbers rather than strings.

Alternatively, you could convert the strings to numbers *after* the csv has been parsed:

```
In [1]: dict1 = {'M1': {'H': '1', 'J' : '2'}, 'M2': {'H': '1', 'J' : '2'}, 'M3': {'H': '1', 'J' : '2'}}

In [2]: dict1 = {key:{k:int(v) for k,v in dct.items()} for key,dct in dict1.items()}

In [3]: dict1
Out[3]: {'M1': {'H': 1, 'J': 2}, 'M2': {'H': 1, 'J': 2}, 'M3': {'H': 1, 'J': 2}}
```

but I think it would be preferable to parse it correctly from the beginning, rather than patch it up this way later.

---

If the dicts contain both numerical and string values, then you could combine them using a join, followed by a groupy and aggregation. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def combine(values):
    if any(isinstance(v, basestring) for v in values):
        result = values.dropna().tolist()
    else:
        result = values.sum()
    return result

dict1 = { 'M1': {'H': 1, 'J' : 2, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF1.txt'},
          'M2': {'H': 1, 'J' : 2, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF2.txt'},
          'M3': {'H': 1, 'J' : 2, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF3.txt'} }
dict2 = { 'M1': {'H': 4, 'J' : 6, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF1.txt'},
          'M2': {'H': 2, 'J' : 5, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF2.txt'},
          'M4': {'H': 9, 'J' : 8, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF3.txt'}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2).T
df = df1.join(df2, rsuffix = '_', how = 'outer').T
grouped = df.groupby(lambda label: label.rstrip('_'))
print(grouped.aggregate(combine).T)
```

yields

```
                               D  H  J
M1  [ABC/DEF1.txt, ABC/DEF1.txt]  5  8
M2  [ABC/DEF2.txt, ABC/DEF2.txt]  3  7
M3                [ABC/DEF3.txt]  1  2
M4                [ABC/DEF3.txt]  9  8
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, the data in csv is mixed. The rows have both integers and strings. In that case, I would like to know if there is a way to add only the numbers and append the 'D' values as a list 

`dict1 = {
          'M1': {'H': 1, 'J' : 2, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF1.txt'}, 
          'M2': {'H': 1, 'J' : 2, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF2.txt'},
          'M3': {'H': 1, 'J' : 2, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF3.txt'}
         }
dict2 = {
'M1': {'H': 4, 'J' : 6, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF1.txt'}, 'M2': {'H': 2, 'J' : 5, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF2.txt'},
         'M4': {'H': 9, 'J' : 8, 'D' : 'ABC/DEF3.txt'}}`